# How to close Activity when DialogFragment is created?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

Let me tell you all what I have done 'till now. I am showing a `dialogfragment` on device screen on a button click working perfectly. But now I want is to close `activity` on button click and show `dialogfragment`.

Code to open `DialogFragment` on button click :

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("dialogData", data);

        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        BuyInfoDilaog dialogFragment = new BuyInfoDilaog();
        dialogFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        dialogFragment.show(fm, "Please Enter your Details");
  }
});
```

How to deal with this case, does anyone have any idea? Please help. Thanks!

Comment: You intend to close the activity that contain the fragment ? I'm not sure to understand

Comment: Attach the dialog to a different context.

Comment: yes i want to close activity but not the fragment created

Comment: You probably want to start a new Activity, with a Dialog theme.

Comment: @TimCastelijns is it possible to attach a dialog with different context ?

Comment: @kapilrajput, you can use "getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(bundle, YourFragment.class.getName(), yourFragment);" to pass your fragment but it's quite bad, you should pass instead the way to create it

Comment: @RenaudFavier thanks but facing exception with your solution `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment is not currently in the FragmentManager`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to do so. The fragment lifecycle is linked with your activity's one. If you finish the activity, it will destroy the fragment.
See :

[image]

You can pass the infos to construct your dialog to your previous activity using startActivityForResult and create the dialog then.

Comment: you're welcome, you can accept it if you're satisfied with it.